# How to set page size in GridView in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I want to set item per page in GridView in view file in a Yii2 project. I know I can set it in DataProvider instance, but I want to set in each view file separately.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why not in the controller before render view?

Comment: Hope this will solve you https://gist.github.com/imanilchaudhari/f4a0668da056453272e4cca2470f79a8

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I hope this could help you

```
 public function actionIndex()
 {
    $searchModel = new ContribuenteSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=15;

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
 }
```