# how to set the amount of items to be shown in yii2 grid view?

Tags: php, mysql, gridview, yii2, yii-extensions

[image]

Controller Code:

```
 public function actionIndex() {
        $searchModel = new ProductSearch();
        if (Yii::$app->request->get('per-page') !== NULL) {
            $searchModel->_pageSize = Yii::$app->request->get('per-page');
        }
        if ($searchModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $searchModel->_pageSize = intval(Yii::$app->request->post()['ProductSearch']['_pageSize']);
            $_SESSION['page_size'] = $searchModel->_pageSize;
        }


            if (isset($_SESSION['page_size']))
            {
                $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, null ,$_SESSION['page_size']);
            }
            else
            {
                $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, null, 20);
            }
            $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=10;
            $this->layout = 'main_ecommerce';
            return $this->render('index', [
                        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

            ]);
```

View code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['page_size']))
                {
                $searchModel->_pageSize = $_SESSION['page_size'];
                }
                Pjax::begin();
                $form = ActiveForm::begin();
                echo $form->field($searchModel, '_pageSize', [
                            'inputOptions' => [
                                    'placeholder' => 'records',
                                    'style' => 'overflow-x: auto;',
                                    'class' => 'form-control input-xsmall input-inline' ],
                        ])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Records : '))
                        ->dropDownList(['10'=> 10, '20' => 20, '50' => 50], ['onchange'=>"this.form.submit();"]);
                ActiveForm::end();
                Pjax::end();
                echo $searchModel->_pageSize;
                ?>
             <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,                 
        'pager' => [
            'options'=>['class'=>'pagination'],   
            'prevPageLabel' => Html::tag('i', "", ['class' => 'fa fa-angle-left']),   
            'nextPageLabel' => Html::tag('i', "", ['class' => 'fa fa-angle-right']),   
            'firstPageLabel'=>Html::tag('i', "", ['class' => 'fa fa-angle-double-left']),  
            'lastPageLabel'=>  Html::tag('i', "", ['class' => 'fa fa-angle-double-right']),   
        ],
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
```

The picture shows that the GridView is only displaying 30 rows of records. How can i adjust this so that i can display, for example 50 records per page. Somehow once i set it already, it keeps showing a value less than the one i set. Why is that?

Comment: you can change page size http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570159/how-to-set-page-size-in-gridview-in-yii2/30572032#30572032

Comment: @scaisEdge i did try that, but it is not showing the number i want. i keeps showing less. for example, when i set $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=15;, it will only show 9 rows. it keeps showing less row then the one i stated

Comment: why you check for page_size  and don't use the normal yii2 features for this  ?  ..

Comment: lets say if i chose to show 50 columns, once i go to another page and click back, the dropdown will show the default instead of my earlier selection. that is why i did it like that

Comment: Explain better what do you mean for "once i go to another page and click back, the dropdown will show the default instead of my earlier selection. " ..

Comment: so basically as i said the page size is suppose to show based on my drop down list selection. so let's say the drop down has 10, 20, and 50 value. So i selected the value 50 and it displays 50 records. when i move to another page, and click back, the drop down will show the top most (which is value 10) instead of my previous selection (which is 50) and show 10 records.

Comment: I understand but i don't know how change dinamucally the page size because this i related  to the limit used by search function for retrieve the rows ..

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=10;
```

in actionIndex before you return searchmodel and dataprovider

for example :

```
    $searchModel = new UserMasterSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->post());

    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=10;

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

Comment: i did that but it is only returning 6 records instead of 10. why is that?

Comment: are you sure you have more than 10 records reutrning from db? if there are only 6 records available then it might be showing 6 records even if page size is 10

Comment: Can you show the code of your controller and view page so that you can get better solutions.

Comment: i edite the code as shown above. actually it is suppose to get the drop down selection and display the page number based on selection. but somehow it keeps showing a value less than the one i set.

Comment: try to print your _pageSize variable of session in action Index and check what value do you get over there. and also check it after saving when you change drop down value. are both same?

Comment: i have checked rushil and they are the same. is it possible somewhere might be causing the problem besides these 2 files?

Comment: i dont think so, because this is managed only by this two files. The only exception now left is from gii. have you done any changes in gii?

Comment: it is possible that one of my old teammates have made changes to the gii. let's say if they did, what files do i need to change then?

Comment: Try composer update or composer install, it will regenerate your vender folder and gii files will get reset. But don't forget to take backup of your project before that, because updating composer will remove extentions which are not mentioned in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Try simply

```
  public function actionIndex() {

      $searchModel =  new ProductSearch();
      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);


        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=10;
        $this->layout = 'main_ecommerce';
        return $this->render('index', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

        ]);
```

and for view

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,                 
    'pager' => [
        'options'=>['class'=>'pagination'],   
        'prevPageLabel' => Html::tag('i', "", ['class' => 'fa fa-angle-left']),   
        'nextPageLabel' => Html::tag('i', "", ['class' => 'fa fa-angle-right']),   
        'firstPageLabel'=>Html::tag('i', "", ['class' => 'fa fa-angle-double-left']),  
        'lastPageLabel'=>  Html::tag('i', "", ['class' => 'fa fa-angle-double-right']),   
    ],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
```

Comment: it is still showing the same problem. instead of the  hardcoded 10, it is showing 6 records only. just for you info i have 20,000+ of records, so it is not because i have less than 10 records

Comment: answer updated .. for  a proper dataProvider  .. let me know