# set pagination for gridview have filters in yii2 basic app

Tags: pagination, yii2

i use yii2 basic app and have gridview with filter and search.
 i want pagination that for each 10 record. what can i do?

i know add pagination in dataprovider but how can add this to my function?

please help me.
this is important for me.
 i do many search but can't find solution for this

controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new ContactSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel'=>$searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

model\contactsearch.php

```
 <?php
 namespace app\models;

 use app\models\Contact;
 use yii\base\Model;
 use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

class ContactSearch extends Contact {
public function rules() {
    return [

        [['f_name', 'l_name', 'phone_number', 'Mobile_number'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

public function scenarios() {
    return Model::scenarios();
}

public function search($params) {
    $query = Contact::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
    'defaultOrder' => [
        'l_name' => SORT_DESC,
    ],

],
    ]);

    if (!(($this->load($params) && $this->validate()))) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'f_name', $this->f_name])
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'l_name', $this->l_name])
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'phone_number', $this->phone_number])
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Mobile_number', $this->Mobile_number]);

          //->andorderBy('id asc');

    return $dataProvider;

}
}

?>
```

view

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'f_name',
        'l_name',
        'phone_number',
        'Mobile_number',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customize record amount in gridview

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
 //show 10 items per page
'pagination' => [
    'pagesize' => 10,
],
    'sort' => [
'defaultOrder' => [
    'l_name' => SORT_DESC,
],
```

Other option is:
[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570159/how-to-set-page-size-in-gridview-in-yii2)

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Article::find()->where(['status' => 1]);
    $countQuery = clone $query;
    $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]);
    $models = $query->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
         'models' => $models,
         'pages' => $pages,
    ]);
}
In view file:

foreach ($models as $model) {
    // display $model here
}

// display pagination
echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pages,
]);
```

Comment: i dont understand your code. what is article,status,clone?

Comment: Article is my modal name, status is column name, based on this am fetching the results. Clone is the predefined function, used to clone the class, object or query etc..